# change Hyper terminal tab title font

Tags: fonts, macbook, tabs, hyperterminal

Using hyper terminal, on mac, and am finding the fonts of unused tabs being too dim, very hard to see (like all the other tabs that aren't in use at the moment). It's like a fine gray color, almost as black as the tab title background. 
Other than that the theme and coloring all configured fine - so I dont want to start playing around with switching themes...
Was hoping for a way to manually modify only the font of the tab ***title***. Like setting a different font color, size, weight, or even background - anything that'll allow me to make title of disabled tabs stand out. 
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you add a picture? They say a picture is better than [108](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/synchromystic/images/e/e1/LOST_clock.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20100417232459) words.